# Certbot and htdig fail with 301 error

Tags: apache2, redirect

I'm building a 2-domain webserver using Ubuntu 23.10 and Apache2. Most of the functions work including certbot for one domain. I've set up the directories for domain1.com and domain2.com. SSL works for domain2.com.

When I run certbot for domain1, I get a fail to redirect. Htdig is a spider that runs though several hierarchical directories of text/html files. Htdig has a web front end that can be used to search the text/html files. I've used htdig on an earlier CenTos6 server (It died a hard death a few months ago. Hence I'm replacing it.)

The htdig indexing fails with an Apache2 301 error, fail to redirect. There should be no redirection. Htdig follows linking via index.html file that link lower level directories.

Can someone point me to a resolution of this 301 error issue? I'm not a pro-sysadmin.